# How to initialize chrono time_point

Tags: c++, time, clock, c++-chrono

I am trying to initialize two `time_point` objects, but when I try to initialize it, it says the `time_point` is a null pointer, which it is but I'm trying to populate it.

So, I have these two `time_point`s:

```
std::chrono::time_point<steady_clock> clock_start;
std::chrono::time_point<steady_clock> clock_end;
```

And I this is my init function:

```
void TimeCounter::initTimeCounter(const seconds sec)
{
    clock_start = steady_clock::now();
    clock_end = steady_clock::now() + sec;
}
```

I also tried to init with my constructor bellow, to see if it would set the values on time point, but it still says that clock_start is a null ptr.

```
TimeCounter::TimeCounter()
{
    clock_start = steady_clock::now();
    clock_end = steady_clock::now();
}
```

Comment: Try adding a complete compilable helloworld to your question.  Otherwise, the problem with your first two lines is there's no such thing as `std`, `chrono`, `time_point`, or `steady_clock`.

Comment: Also showing us the exact compiler error messages helps.  That will help us infer some of your code that you're so far not showing us.

Comment: I have the using keyword for steady_clock, but C++11 does have a Chrono library: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono . You might be confusing with the boost Chrono library. My error is not a compile error, but a run-time error, saying that clock_start is a null ptr, a writing access violation.

Comment: Excellent clarification.  Can you show us a complete program that exhibits this run time error?  Try to whittle it down to the minimum amount of code necessary to demonstrate the symptom.  Part of our confusion lies in that `clock_start` as you've shown it is clearly not any kind of pointer, and thus can not be a null pointer.

Comment: Oh, you're right. I did create a pointer based on my class above, the error kept sending me to my init function, so I thought that was the root of the problem.

Comment: Ok, good.  `chrono` on!  Obligatory link to `chrono` tutorial :-)  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P32hvk8b13M